# MySQL - Update a column after information get's inserted

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table in MySql table like the following

```
row_timestamp timestamp
, row_id int(11) auto_increment
, mrn char(17)
, patients_last_name varchar(50)
, patients_first_name varchar(50)
, ssn char(4) default '0000'
, visit_key NULL
```

upon the insertion of a record, I'd like visit_key to bet set to `visit_key = concat(mrn, row_id)` I was trying to accomplish this with a before insert trigger to no avail, I kept getting that the mrn column was not in the field select list.

**Update**

I tried the following, which seems not to work because the auto_increment has not yet incremented:

```
set new.visit_key = concat(new.mrn, new.row_id)
```

I also tried

```
set new.visit_key = concat(new.mrn, max(row_id)+1)
```

I am thinking of the trigger to sort of act like a calculated field in MS Access, is this reasonable? Thoughts? Would it not be possible to do since the visit_key would technically be `NULL` and you cannot update a new value?

**UPDATE**

I used the following code that I adapted from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539403/mysql-trigger-after-insert-update)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER vkt AFTER INSERT ON demographic_information
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE `demographic_information` SET visit_key_test = concat(new.mrn, mew.row_id) WHERE row_id = NEW.row_id;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

and got the following error message:

```
INSERT INTO  `manchuco_nys_trauma`.`demographic_information` (

`row_timestamp` ,
`row_id` ,
`mrn` ,
`patients_last_name` ,
`patients_first_name` ,
`ssn` ,
`visit_id` ,
`visit_key_test`
)
VALUES (

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , NULL ,  '123456',  'Sanderson',  'Steven',  '1234',  '12345670', NULL
)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1442 - Can't update table 'demographic_information' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Thank you,

Comment: Edit your question and provide the code for your trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the auto increment value inside the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON yourTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE next_id integer;
    SET next_id = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
                   FROM information_schema.TABLES
                   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='yourDB' AND TABLE_NAME='yourTable');
    SET new.visit_key = CONCAT(new.mrn, next_id);
END
```

I discovered this approach in [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469009/can-you-access-the-auto-increment-value-in-mysql-within-one-statement).

Comment: this is not working I get an error checking syntax for my version of MySQL, seems there is an issue with the DECLARE next_id INT;

Comment: I will get it tonight

Answer (score 0):

What you observe seems normal: since you're using **BEFORE** INSERT the `id` value doen't exist yet.
And the same applies for your try with `concat(new.mrn, **new**.row_id)`: NEW has no sense at the moment.

So I suggest you use AFTER INSERT instead.

Comment: I tried doing after insert as well and I got a message that I cannot do that.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator What exactly was the message?

Comment: I'll screenshot it when I get home, logging into my cpanel has been labeled verboten by the network...

Comment: updating of NEW record is not allowed in AFTER INSERT

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Hmm... Seems to mean that you've used `concat(new.mrn, new.row_id)`: try change it for `concat(old.mrn, old.row_id)`. And BTW, use `UPDATE SET...` in your AFTER INSERT